# Reading JSON data using Java

Tags: java, json

I have a 500,000 line json file I'm trying to read, I tried out a few online examples like mkyong's and many others, but this format is a first encounter for me. Can anyone help me to get started?

I'm using json-simple library.

Any enlighten on this topic? I'll be very grateful

```
 {
"info": {
    "category": "url", 
    "started": "2013-11-07 03:44:32", 
    "ended": "2013-11-07 03:46:55", 
    "version": "0.6", 
    "duration": 143, 
    "id": 37
}, 
"signatures": [], 
"static": {}, 
"dropped": [
    {
        "yara": [], 
        "sha1": "6fd9eb6a42fd531988fba24137a2fe29ad992465", 
        "name": "tia[1].png", 
        "type": "PNG image data, 27 x 23, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced", 
        "sha256": "75d6d26afb9506145d7f6472555855ef4305e0ef3e7cf4cb3d943c58123c7f74", 
        "crc32": "FDCAC92F", 
        "path": "/home/user/cuckoo/storage/analyses/37/files/2435944344/tia[1].png", 
        "ssdeep": null, 
        "size": 387, 
        "sha512": "b47ca17050ff4b6ddab848195c17b875454aafbec06d07bba126e553c9d32647f461adee9d1a75bbfffa08d6a8fc955429562794b123bebc9ec23dc89bdefcc5", 
        "md5": "ad07ee4cb98da073dda56ce7ceb88f5a"
    }
 ]
}
```

REPLY

**I currently don't understand how i can get the array in [dropped], I did some of the easier example, but this is a first for me. It seems like there a hierarchy but I don't know how to access it**

Comment: Do you need help understanding the JSON format itself, or how to parse it with json-simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not start with the [json-simple decoding examples](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples)? If it's the size of the file you're worried about, then you should use the 'SAX' style example. This code would be a good example of how not to do it. See the other comment for better ideas.

```
JSONObject data= (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(new InputStreamReader(JsonSimpleEx.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.json")) );
JSONArray dropped = (JSONArray)data.get("dropped");
JSONObject first = (JSONObject)dropped.get(0);
System.out.println( first.get("crc32"));
```

Comment: Oh gosh... I just figure it out when I saw this, my code is quite similar to yours. I find that when dealing with such a large json file this gets quite messy at times. What's a good way of coding then? using the SAX creating a class file specific to the fields that I want to collect? Thanks for all this enlighten.

Comment: The better way to code it is to create plain old java objects (POJO's) with elements that match the structure of your json data. A good json library will simply create new instances of those objects and return them to you so that you can get to the data by using your Java objects. Since I don't see anything like that in the json-simple examples I'm going to assume it doesn't support that. Most json libraries support this feature. For example, in the Gson library it is called 'deserialization'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gson - from Google](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). It is simple and concise.

You need to declare your Java POJO that represents your JSON data, like:

```
public class Info {
   private Category category;
   ...
}
```

Hope this help. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks :) currently looking at Gson, I'm using this json-simple lib, which I suspect is lacking a few good feature I need.

Answer (score 0):

write and read this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "Bart",
    "lastname": "Simpson",
    "address": {
      "city": "Springfield",
      "country": "USA"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstname": "Homer",
    "lastname": "Simpson",
    "address": {
      "city": "Springfield",
      "country": "USA"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "firstname": "Mickey",
    "lastname": "Mouse",
    "address": {
      "city": "Orlando",
      "country": "USA"
    }
  }
```

PersonJson:

```
public class PersonJSON {
    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private AddressJSON address;
    
    public PersonJSON(int id, String firstname, String lastname, AddressJSON address)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    
    public AddressJSON getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(AddressJSON address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "id: " + this.id + " - Firstname: " + this.firstname + " - Lastname: " + this.lastname + ", " + getAddress().toString();
    }
}
```

AddressJson:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class AddressJSON {
    //@SerializedName("Cidade")
    private String city;
    private String country;
    
    public AddressJSON(String city, String country)
    {
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return city + ", " + country;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;

public class PDJSON {

    private List<PersonJSON> people;

    public PDJSON() {
        people = new ArrayList<PersonJSON>();
    }

    public void saveData(String filePath) {
        //Gson gson = new Gson();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        
        try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filePath)){
            gson.toJson(people, fw);        
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<PersonJSON> loadData(String filePath) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonReader jsonReader = null;

        final Type CUS_LIST_TYPE = new TypeToken<List<PersonJSON>>() {}.getType();
        //or TypeToken.getParameterized(ArrayList.class, PersonJSON.class).getType();
        
        try{
            jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return gson.fromJson(jsonReader, CUS_LIST_TYPE); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PDJSON pdj = new PDJSON();
        pdj.people.add(new PersonJSON(1,"Bart", "Simpson", new AddressJSON("Springfield", "USA")));
        pdj.people.add(new PersonJSON(2,"Homer", "Simpson", new AddressJSON("Springfield", "USA")));
        pdj.people.add(new PersonJSON(3,"Mickey", "Mouse", new AddressJSON("Orlando", "USA")));

        pdj.saveData("resources/listofpeople.json");

        List<PersonJSON> lp = pdj.loadData("resources/listofpeople.json"); 
        for(PersonJSON pj : lp)
        {
            System.out.println(pj.toString());
        }
    }
}
```